# Using sprite sheet for button images

Tags: android

How to use a spritesheet to put a section of  spritesheet as a background image of the Buttons in Android?
  Please consider me as a noob. I have just started to learn android app development.What I want is I have a spritesheet where there are several images,in that I just want to put a particular section of the spritesheet as the background image of the button rather than having image.png for each individual buttons in the app.

Answer (score 0):

See this question, you can find different ways to achieve this :
[Spritesheet programmatically cutting: best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341017/spritesheet-programmatically-cutting-best-practices)

But if you haven't a large number of images, you should cut them into drawables, it's easier for sure.