# Android - Optimum Image Size for App Performance and Quality

Tags: java, android, image, png

I want to know what would be the optimum size of the each png image file in the application?

By the time I complete the game application I assume that there will be more than 50 .png images included

in the application. I want each png image to be of high quality and maximize performance of the

application (I do not want any lag spike in my game application..).

Is there any quick approach to find the optimum image size?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `the optimum image size`? For what? To fill the screen? To be used as an icon?

Comment: No to be appeared as an image on the screen. For instance, images for monsters, tower, and etc. for the game. I want them to be of high quality while the image size does not disturb any performance of the application

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible to know an *optimum* size, but for sprites for a game, as it sounds like you want, you might try a sprite sheet. This question has a bit more information.
[Spritesheet programmatically cutting: best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341017/spritesheet-programmatically-cutting-best-practices)

If you don't want to go through that, try just compressing your images as much as possible either using jpg compression, or a service like http://www.tinypng.org

Comment: Mmmm... I think that he should not compress images. As it will take time to decompress them.

Comment: I was also thinking for using the spritesheet but if the size of spritesheet gets bigger and bigger wouldn't it reduce the performance as well? or is there any set rules to make an optimum size for it? I was also thinking about compressing images but I am afraid if it will reduce quality.. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: You won't really see a loss of quality unless you look down to the pixel level of the image using tinypng. Even then, the change isn't noticeable, they use a pretty good algorithm to conserve colors while downsampling to png8

Comment: It would reduce performance, which is why it would be good to only include related sprites in the same sheet, such as with an animation.