# Working with sprite sheet animations in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, sprite, sprite-sheet

I have been doing a lot of research, but I cannot find a clear example on rendering a spritesheet as an animation. I have this sprite sheet:

[image]

I will appreciate a lot of sample code on loading this efficiently

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spritesheet programmatically cutting: best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341017/spritesheet-programmatically-cutting-best-practices)

Comment: Can I ask if you are developing a graphic intensive application like game or not? If so, my first suggesstion is to completely switch to a game engine like LibGDX or ANDengine.

Answer (score 7):

The way of doing this is pretty simple,

What you'll need before you start to code to separate your sprite into different separate image files, each files represents a frame in your animation. 
Note: You can achieve the above via code, but that's another issue.

**1.** Now you will need to create an xml file that will be your animation.
**The xml will be in res/drawble**.

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/exp0" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/exp1" android:duration="100"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/exp2" android:duration="100"/>
    .
    .
```

Where each item, is a frame (by order) - exp0 is the first frame exp1 is he second and so on.

```
android:oneshot="true"
```

Will make your animation go through the loop once and then keep the last frame displayed. The rest of the code is pretty self-explanatory (duration is in millis).

**2.** You will need to assign the xml file to a View and start it.

Lets say we want this animation to be displayed on a "tileView" object in a grid (You can do so to any View)

```
    tileView.setImageResource(R.drawable.explosion_animation);
    AnimationDrawable explosionAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)tileView.getDrawable();
    explosionAnimation.start();
```

What we do here is set the xml that is our animation  as the ImageResource (explosion_animation is the xml file we created)
Then we get the animation itself into an AnimationDrawable object.
Finally we start the animation.

Answer (score 4):

You can store the sprites as an array of `Rect`s.

```
Rect[] frames = new Rect[TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_FRAMES];
```

Your sheet appears to have equally spaced sprites, so you could have a nested for loop that fills the array mathematically. (Note you may want to set BitMapFactory Options to not scale your bitmap).

You can draw the nth frame with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, frames[n],
    new RectF(x, y, x + frames[n].width(), y + frames[n].height()),
    paint);
```