# Extract an image from a PNG image using its background position

Tags: java, android, image

I want to extract a set of images from a PNG file using their background position (like we do in a CSS file).

The main PNG file is [List Of Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIuqz.png) and I want to get each country flag separately.

Is there any way in Android to extract those flags programmatically?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: explain what is your requirement properly. Didn't get what you want

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip  for cliping

Comment: also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/7341017/3496570

Comment: Thanks Nepster, I thought my question was clear and straight. Anyway, I got the solution for this issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load file into Bitmap

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
// selected_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);   // if you need
```

2. Access each pixel array

```
int dstWidth = width of the flag rectangle;
int dstHeight = height of the flag rectangle;
int pixelArray[] = new int[dstWidth * dstHeight];

int startX = start X position of your flag;
int endX = end X position of your flag;
int startY = start Y position of your flag;
int endX = end Y position of your flag;

bitmap.getPixels(pixelArray, 0, startX, startX, startY, dstWidth, dstHeight);
```

3. Create a small Bitmap with array

```
Bitmap flag = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(pixelArray);
```

Comment: Thanks @Suhyeon Lee, I thought there is another solution rather than using the Bitmap decoding method, but it's alright, I will see if this solution works for me ;)